# Chrome redireciona localhost para produção

Tags: google-chrome

Não sei se é o lugar certo para postar essa pergunta, se eu estiver errado por favor me corrijam.

Enfim, estou tentando acessar meu `localhost/passagem` e ele me redireciona para o site de produção.

Já tentei limpar Cache com `CTRL+F5`, `SHIFT+CTRL+F5` e `CTRL+R`, e também, o Hard Reload do Google Chrome. Já tentei também fazer também a reinstalação do Chrome que também não resolveu.

Segui os passos do Stack gringo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277457/google-chrome-redirecting-localhost-to-https e também não deu certo.

Fiz alguns testes, tentei acessar o localhost pelo IP 127.0.0.1 e deu certo, entretanto, pelo 127.0.1.1 ele redireciona para produção.

Meu arquivo hosts (/etc/hosts) tem os seguintes IP's:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   rodoviario
```

Já tentei alterar o 127.0.1.1 para 127.0.0.1 e rodoviario para localhost e também não consegui.

Alguém faz idéia o porque isso acontece?

Comment: Qual servidor web? Qual linguagem de programação? Será que seu programa não tem alguma referência ao hostname de produção entãos links gerados estão por exemplo: `<a href='https://producao.com'> home </a>`?

Comment: Muito provavelmente quem está te redirecionando é `localhost/passagem`, não o Chrome.

Comment: O servidor web é apache e a linguagem é PHP com HTML e JS

Comment: é engraçado que o Mozilla não da esse problema

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o problema

No header.php do meu projeto havia uma condicional que se o IP não fosse 127.0.0.1 ele redirecionava para produção.

Acontece que o Chrome acessa o localhost em IPv6 (::1) por isso estava redirecionando.